# Brains, Kinked Veins, and Pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

My physics has degraded from mathematical to intuitive, always a problem.  Asking for help with what appears to be a simple problem that starts here:

> fluid flowing in a tube at a given flow rate encounters a constriction reducing the area of the tube.  This will create a pressure gradient related to Bernoulli's Principle;

I need clarification on the relationship between that pressure gradient under conditions of increased flow (volume/time)?  Is this linear or exponential?

Comment: Might [this](https://www.engr.colostate.edu/~pierre/ce_old/classes/CIVE%20401/Team%20reports/2%20-%20Minor%20Losses%20in%20Pipes%20-%20Balsiger%20Bastos%20Behm.pdf) help? As a first approximation you can model a constriction as a succession of contraction and expansion in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

If a liquid goes through a *smaller* area, the speed goes *up* by the ratio of the areas to get all the mass through.

If the speed goes *up*, the pressure goes *down* by the square because $\rm{P}+1/2\rho V^2$ doesn’t change.

So 1/2 the area is 1/4 the pressure, 1/3 the area is 1/9th the pressure, etc. no exponentials.

Comment: That is where I've been ending up, so I'm missing something in the model or not explaining it properly.

Comment: Assume the system to be a tube with area A1.  It is level; h1/h2/g factor to zero.  An segment with reduced area (A2) is present.  As flow through the system increases, a critical threshold is reached where pressure on the input side of the constriction increases, and continues to rise as flow increases.  I presume this is due to a limit of the constriction to allow a given mass segment to transit the constricted segment at the same rate as the input flow.  I'm interested in the relationship of how pressure rises relative to increased flow beyond the critical level, and why.

Comment: BTW, your explanation of speed/pressure/area is very helpful, thank you.  I've read where Bernoulli starts to fall apart in this type of system, but having to relearn old things and add new.  This is an initial step in building and explaining a more complex physiologic system.

Comment: The increase of pressure on the inlet (pre-restriction) side is related to additional physics: drag due to viscosity. Those calculations depend on the behavior of the pump.  It’s it’s providing _pressure_, drag just results in reduced flow. If it’s providing flow (I.e. fixed volume per second), then the pressure has to rise to provide a fixed flow. Most real cases are in between.

Comment: The restriction increases drag from (1) turbulence at the restriction if the flow isn’t smooth there and (2) increased wall drag because a larger of the flow is close enough to the wall to be in the turbulent boundary layer.

Comment: I'm hugely simplifying the system at this point to understand each step.  The system will have a static pressure absent flow; a pump provides flow of the pressurized fluid.  As I talk this out, I'm interested chiefly in the concept that below a critical flow rate, the constriction allows flow without pressure buildup.  a

Comment: Had to add this due to the 5 minute edit rule: OK, getting somewhere.  The system has a certain pressure  without any flow that can vary within a range; a pump moves adds flow to that pressurized fluid.  What I'm trying to determine is whether test conditions that artificially lower system pressure as well as flow might mask a pressure gradient that would be seen under normal use.  Intuition tells me yes, and the testing conditions I'm seeing reduce both static pressure and flow below those that would normally be experienced, and thus, potential areas of concern are not identified.

Comment: BTW, guessing boundary drag and turbulence increase with fluid viscocity? _P_  in Bernoulli?  (apologies, still experimenting with the formatting).

Comment: Not sure I understand the system you're describing, sorry.  Yes, drag and turbulence increase with viscosity.  Bernoulli's equation has no concept of drag or energy loss, and doesn't include viscosity; the $P$ there is Pressure.  There are several kinds of viscosity that are usually denoted by various greek letters; see the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity

Comment: Ahh, my weakness with words.  The system is a rigid tube containing a liquid at a static pressure.  There is a constriction in the tube.  I posit that this system will allow a certain flow before drag and turbulence will cause a pressure gradient to develop across the constriction.  Thus, if this system is tested without raising the flow to the critical level, a critical problem may not become evident.  That's about as well as I'm able to describe it.  I need to know if this initial supposition is accurate before building upon it.  Thank you so much for your help.